# how to get the value from group radio button

Tags: php

I am trying to get the value from the radio boxes/button with php.

The server only supports PHP.

I did the code in asp.net(C#) tried to test found server does not support asp.net.

The create same questionnaire in JavaScript. Now finding out some of external clients are using browser date back to IE 7. So need to re-code in php

All radio box have numeric values

example:`<label>
                        <input type="radio" name="experiencebx" value="5" id="experiencebx_0"/>
                        Brand New</label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="experiencebx" value="10" id="experiencebx_1"/>
                        Less than 2 years</label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="experiencebx" value="15" id="experiencebx_2"/>
                        2-5 years</label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="experiencebx" value="20" id="experiencebx_3"/>
                        5-10 years</label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="experiencebx" value="30" id="experiencebx_4"/>
                        10+ years</label>`

how do I loop through and grab the value and

total at the bottoms.

Second question is

How to pass the total to a second page make a subtotal to add that number to the final total.

in ASP.net I can store the number in a session.

Last question:

Take the text of the selected radio button/boxes and the select radio button/boxes value email them to me.

I really, really, need some help.

Comment: Those are quite a few steps you have there.  Perhaps working through a PHP tutorial would be a first good step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for question one:

use $_POST["experiencebx"] to get the value selected.

for question #2:

use a session with $_SESSION["var"] = "value";

for question #3:

use the mail function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: don't forget to add start_session(); before headers are sent, and use var_dump(); to debug ;)

Comment: It's `session_start()` not `start_session()`

Comment: Sorry, wrote that too quickly...!

Comment: I really appreciate your help I just don't understand. <?php
 session_start();
if(isset($_POST['next']))
{
 {
  $exptotal = $_POST['experiencebx'];
  $total = 0;
      foreach($subtotal as $exptotal)
      { 
     $answer = $total + $subtotal;
      }
 }
}

?>

Comment: I really appreciate your help I just don't understand. <?php
 session_start();
if(isset($_POST['next']))
{
 {
  $exptotal = $_POST['experiencebx'];
  $total = 0;
      foreach($subtotal as $exptotal)
      { 
     $answer = $total + $subtotal;
      }
 }
}

?>  The ['next'] is a button to go to page 2.  the session part I get. similar to asp.net and the mail form as well much easier. I just having problem with radio and check boxes. trying echo the total numeric values to see if works getting Notice: Undefined variable: answers I have this setup on a textbox <?php echo $answer ?>

Comment: ensure you do post them via a form, checking the elements then clicking a link won't do, your next link must be a submit button to a parent form element.

Comment: thanks dude something so simple. I had the input type="button" instead of submit thanks